# My Emacs mode does not highlight keywords

Tags: emacs

I am trying to write an Emacs major mode but it is not working; specifically, my keywords are not being displayed in keyword font face. I have tried to follow the tutorials but I must be doing something wrong. I know a little Lisp but I do not know Emacs scripting.

My Emacs mode script:

```
;; emacs mode for OldRope
;; does no work for some reason
(setq oldrope-directive-keywords-regexp (regexp-opt  '("page" "link" "goto" "act" "end" "div" "span" "include")))
(defvar oldrope-font-lock-defaults  '((
                       (oldrope-directive-keywords-regexp . font-lock-keyword-face))))
(define-derived-mode oldrope-mode fundamental-mode
  "oldrope mode"
  "Major mode for editing OldRope games"
  (setq comment-start "/*")
  (setq comment-end "*/")
  (setq font-lock-defaults oldrope-font-lock-defaults))
(provide 'oldrope-mode)
```

Test file:

```
$[page start]$ Hello $[link]$ Click me $[act]$ That is right. $[end]$
```

(For context, this is part of https://github.com/martinellison/oldrope but that is not really relevant to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this - the rest is OK:

```el
 (defvar oldrope-font-lock-defaults
         `(((,oldrope-directive-keywords-regexp . font-lock-keyword-face))))
```

By simply quoting the list you were not evaluating `oldrope-directive-keywords-regexp` - your quoted list just had that symbol as its car.

Using either backquote (`` ` ``) plus comma (`,`) or `(list (list (cons oldrope-directive-keywords-regexp 'font-lock-keyword-face)))` you evaluate that variable and use its value in the resulting list.